# Is possible to auto generate documentation for pytest tests?

Tags: pytest, python-sphinx

I have a project which contains only pytest tests, without modules or classes, which test remote project.
E.g. structure ->

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── test_basic_auth_app.py
├── test_basic_auth_user.py
├── test_advanced_app_id.py
├── test_advanced_user.py
└── test_oauth_auth.py
```

Tests look like

```py
"""
Service requires credentials (app_id, app_key) to be passed using the Basic Auth

"""
import base64

import pytest

import authorising.auth
from authorising.resources import Service


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def service_settings(service_settings):
    "Set auth mode to app_id/app_key"
    service_settings.update({"backend_version": Service.Auth_app})
    return service_settings

def test_basic_auth_app_id_key(application):
    """Test client access with Basic HTTP Auth using app id and app key

    Configure Api/Service to use App ID / App Key Authentication
    and Basic HTTP Auth to pass the credentials.
    """

    credentials = application.authobj.credentials
    encoded = base64.b64encode(
        f"{creds['app_id']}:{credentials['app_key']}".encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")

    response = application.test_request()

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.request.headers["Auth"] == "Basic %s" % encoded
```

**Is it possible to auto generate documentation from docstrings e.g using Sphinx ?**

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html.

Comment: I have tried that but automodule or autoclass doesn't work because I have no classes or modules.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A Python file such as `test_basic_auth_app.py` corresponds to the `test_basic_auth_app` module. But perhaps I misunderstand because I don't know much about pytest.

Comment: To me it looks like you have several modules that are in a package (indicated by `__init__.py`). See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sphinx-apidoc` to generate test-documentation automatically using `python-docstrings`

For instance, if you have directory structure like below

```
.
docs
  |-- rst
  |-- html
tests
  ├── __init__.py
  ├── test_basic_auth_app.py
  ├── test_basic_auth_user.py
  ├── test_advanced_app_id.py
  ├── test_advanced_user.py
  └── test_oauth_auth.py
```

```
sphinx-apidoc -o docs/rst tests
sphinx-build  -a -b  html docs/rst docs/html -j auto
```

All Your docs HTML Files will be under `docs/html`.

There are multiple options `sphinx-apidoc` supports. Here is the [link]: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html

Answer (score 0):

When using sphinx, you should add your test-folder to the Python path in the `conf.py` file:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'tests')))
```

Then in each rst file you can simply write:

```
.. automodule:: test_basic_auth_app
   :members:
```

If you want to document also the test results, please take a look into [Sphinx-Test-Reports](https://sphinx-test-reports.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)